# How add a slideshow in leaflet (typescript)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, leaflet

I use leaflet on typescript.

```
marker.bindPopup(
                `
      <img src='${imgList[0]}'>
      <a href='http://toto.fr/?id=${markerData.id}'>show details</a>
   `
            )
            .openPopup();
```

I want to loop through an object to create a slideshow of pictures in the "Popup". Do you have a solution please ?

Thank :)

Answer (score 0):

Using leaflet: this will work https://dotnetfiddle.net/jKbPOZ

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index7</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
          integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
          crossorigin="" />
    <style>
        #mapid {
            height: 180px;
        }

        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
        }

        img {
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        /* Slideshow container */
        .slideshow-container {
            max-width: 1000px;
            position: relative;
            margin: auto;
        }
        /* Caption text */
        .text {
            color: #f2f2f2;
            font-size: 15px;
            padding: 8px 12px;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 8px;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
        }
        /* Number text (1/3 etc) */
        .numbertext {
            color: #f2f2f2;
            font-size: 12px;
            padding: 8px 12px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
        }
        /* The dots/bullets/indicators */
        .dot {
            height: 15px;
            width: 15px;
            margin: 0 2px;
            background-color: #bbb;
            border-radius: 50%;
            display: inline-block;
            transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
        }

        .active {
            background-color: #717171;
        }
        /* Fading animation */
        .fade {
            -webkit-animation-name: fade;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
            animation-name: fade;
            animation-duration: 1.5s;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
            integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
            crossorigin=""></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {

            function newMap(mapId) {
                if (mapId == 1) {
                    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                    }).addTo(map);

                    L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map) /*england*/
                        .bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup.<br> Easily customizable.')
                        .openPopup();
                } else if (mapId == 2) {
                    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                    }).addTo(map);

                    L.marker([33, -112]).addTo(map)  /*city2*/
                        .bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup.<br> Easily customizable.')
                        .openPopup();
                } else if (mapId == 3) {
                    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                    }).addTo(map);

                    L.marker([42, -71]).addTo(map)  /*city3*/
                        .bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup.<br> Easily customizable.')
                        .openPopup();
                }
            }

            var map = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
            /************slide show */
            var slideIndex = 0;
            showSlides();
            function showSlides() {
                var i;
                var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
                slideIndex++;
                if (slideIndex > 3) { slideIndex = 1 } //3 is number of slides
                for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
                    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
                }

                newMap(slideIndex);
                dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
                setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
            }
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div id="mapid"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align:center">
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks to https: w3schools and leaflet site

Comment: I have a map then i cant use your solution.